# Converting Nestjs with graphql prisma to serverless, error starting up

Tags: graphql, nestjs, serverless, prisma, serverless-offline

I am having some trouble with converting Nestjs to serverless.
My tech stack is, Nestjs, Graphql and Prisma.
I have followed multiple guide buy to no avail, below are the tutorials I have follow.
https://nishabe.medium.com/nestjs-serverless-lambda-aws-in-shortest-steps-e914300faed5
https://github.com/lnmunhoz/nestjs-graphql-serverless

The error that i am facing.
It happens when i start to navigate to it. Example, http://localhost:3000/dev/graphql, I wanted to access the playground

[image]

The problem shows that serverless file is missing, but its there under src

This is my serverless.ts file inside src folder

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { ExpressAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { Context, Handler } from 'aws-lambda';
import serverless from 'aws-serverless-express';
import express from 'express';
import { Server } from 'http';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

export async function bootstrap() {
  const expressApp = express();
  const adapter = new ExpressAdapter(expressApp);
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, adapter);

  await app.init();
  return serverless.createServer(expressApp);
}

let cachedServer: Server;

export const handler: Handler = async (event: any, context: Context) => {
  if (!cachedServer) {
    const server = await bootstrap();
    cachedServer = server;
    return serverless.proxy(server, event, context);
  } else {
    return serverless.proxy(cachedServer, event, context);
  }
};
```

And this is my serverless.yml file

```
service: laundry-api

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: ap-southeast-1
  stage: dev
  profile: default # Config your AWS Profile

plugins:
  - serverless-offline

functions:
  index:
    handler: src/serverless.handler
    environment:
      SLS_DEBUG: true
    events:
      - http:
          path: graphql
          method: any
          cors: true
```

I have been cracking my head for hours on where is the problem, tried webpack too.
Would be greate if you guys can point me to the right direction
Thank you.